# Counting with Query

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am using queries, in order to create a dashboard,

```
=query('Usuarios icorp'!I2:M522; "count(F) when F contains '"&B3&"' ", -1)
```

I am having issues with my query function.

I want to count how many times the value of a cell (character), in this case B3, is within a table.

Answer (score 1):

It was a syntax issue, my data range was incorrect.